# Change and save smoke/particles color

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, color

Newish to blender. I want to change the Rainbow CC Node color from blue to red. Every time I change it to red it renders blue and the colors reset back to blue. Any help is appreciated!!! [image: Screenshot]

Comment: It looks like you set some keyframes. If you change the color but do not create a new keyframe for the change, then it will revert to the previously set value.

Comment: Can I edit by going to the dopesheet and selecting the keyframe? or do I have to delete and add new?

Comment: Either deleting the keyframes or overwriting them would work. The idea is that if there is a keyframe with a set value it overrides any changes unless those changes are made permanent with another keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

The border around the colour swatch indicates that it is keyframed, which is causing the colour to go back to it's animated setting. The border on the colour swatch is equivalent to the green and yellow backgrounds of keyframed numeric values.

Right click <kbd>[image: RMB]</kbd> on the colour and choose "Clear Keyframes" to remove all of the animated data. The border will then disappear and your colour selection will stay.

If you only want the colour to change at a certain part of your animation, then you need to add keyframes to make the colour change when you want it to.